# How to Authenticate users via a code which needs to be sent to mail

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization

Requirement : Need to allow users to sign in to an app by providing their username and a code needs to be generated and sent to the email. When user enters the code we need to allow him to the system and generate a Azure AD generated token.

Already we have a form in React where user can enter username and password and can login to the system.
using `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` with the autority we are validating the username and password and getting the token.

```
var authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", myTenant);
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
IPublicClientApplication app;
app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(myAudience).WithDefaultRedirectUri().WithAuthority(authority).Build();
string decryptedPassword = DecryptStringAES(password);
var res =  await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, decryptedPassword).ExecuteAsync();
```

Now we need to allow users to the system by entering the secret code sent to his mail and generate this token